# AngularJS страница не отображается полностью

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Есть главная страница и вторичная, на которую можно перейти с главной. В каждой странице `header` описан на `html`, а дальше `body` грузится как `angularjs ng-app`, и обрабатывается с помощью `RenderBody()`. Проблема в том что контроллеры двух страниц зависят от фабрики `ticketCache`:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('Application', [])
        .factory('ticketCache', ['$cacheFactory',function($cacheFactory) {
            var self = this;
            self.cache = $cacheFactory('ticketCache');

            return {
                get: function(key) {
                    return self.cache.get(key);
                },
                put: function(key, value) {
                    self.cache.put(key, value);
                },
                putList: function(list) {
                    list.forEach(function(item) {
                        self.cache.put(item.Id, item);
                    });
                },
                erase: function () {
                    self.cache.removeAll();
                }
            };
        }]);
})();
```

Если я оставляю так `angular.module('Application', [])`, то на главной странице не грузится `body`, а вторичная страница загружается нормально, если же убираю и оставляю вот так `angular.module('Application')`, то происходит наоборот, главной нету, вторичная полностью. 
Из за чего это может быть? Как решить этот вопрос?